# toggle pie chart data using external button

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to toggle data on a highchart pie chart, but I could only find how to show/hide an entire series. Basically I want to replicate the legend behavior using my own buttons.

```
// the button action
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    $button = $('#button');
$button.click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[0];
    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();
        $button.html('Show series');
    } else {
        series.show();
        $button.html('Hide series');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/JLrc2/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you want to hide point/slice, not series. Then try to use `.setVisible(true/false)`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/JLrc2/3/

```
// the button action
var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    $button = $('#button');
$button.click(function() {
    var ff = chart.series[0].data[0];
    if (ff.visible) {
        ff.setVisible(false);
        $button.html('Show firefox');
    } else {
        ff.setVisible(true);
        $button.html('Hide firefox');
    }
});
```